# Facebook Desktop Application C++

Tags: c++, desktop, facebook-apps

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial for developing a desktop facebook application in c++.

I went through the facebook documentation about applicatiion development. What are the parameters that need to be specified while creating an application in facebook.

---

Its possible to upload photos to facebook via a C++ desktop application.

I got it solved.

Answer (score 2):

These open source libraries with examples might be what you're looking for

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-cpp-graph-api/

http://projects.seligstein.com/facebook/

Comment: thanks for your reply. The first link gives a demo application. It would be nice if you can help me out with a step by step tutorial. Requirement is to develop an application without using any SDK. The second link uses rest API. But the reuirement is to use oauth 2.0. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: The facebook docs seems pretty ok to me.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: i went through that site. my doubt is regarding the oauth format used in the url.